# Unicode mirror character?

Tags: unicode, security

‮?retcarahc "rorrim" edocinu eht htiw detaicossa ytilibarenluv fo tros emos ereht sI
?ksir yna ereht erA ?rof ti si tahW

Comment: The official name of the character U+202E is "OVERRIDE, RIGHT-TO-LEFT". Just FYI.

Comment: Officially, "Mirrored" is a property of characters "(", ")", "༺", "༻", etc.

Answer (score 35):

We've talked about attacks using the RLO (U+202E RIGHT TO LEFT OVERRIDE) character in the past, which shifts the 'visual' display of a string from the position it's placed inside that string.  So for example:

document[U+202E]fdp.exe visually looks like documentexe.pdf

I talked about these and other attacks of this sort here http://www.casaba.com/products/UCAPI/.  In fact we're starting to hear of real world attacks using these techniques to bypass spam and other filters.  Firefox closed a bug in their file download dialog box.

I see a big difference between attacks leveraging BIDI text and the playful sort of 'mirror' effects you get from tools like [txtn.us](https://web.archive.org/web/20101129035512/http://txtn.us/mirror-words-flip-text-reverse-words-upside-down-words-and-text).

!luʇmɿɒʜ ƨɒ mɘɘƨ ƚ'nƨɘob ƚxɘƚ bɘɿoɿɿim ɘʜƚ

Answer (score 14):

Well, you can abuse it for pishing attacks. Take this URL for example:

```
 ‮http://www.example.com?site/moc.elgoog.www//:ptth
```

It looks like if you click it it will take you to google.com, where in reality it will take you to example.com. Not all browsers support it, though.

Comment: Oh please note that this dosnt work with all browsers. I was just viewing it on chrome for mobile and the mirror char is compleatly ignored here...

Comment: Does any browser support it?  That sounds like a bug.

Comment: I certainly believe no browser nor URL library should support it. But since it's a regular char in the unicode space if no proper exceptions have been made in the application's URL encoding then it will work. Thus, I'd see it as a potentialy exploitable bug.

Comment: As of September 2023, Opera GX (which is based on Chromium) still directs me to example.com.

Answer (score 11):

There are no digital risks, but there can be human risks as it may cause things to be misread or misinterpreted.

Comment: What do you consider to be the boundary between a "digital risk" and a "human risk", in the context of a human interacting with the digital world?  Seems like a fuzzy line, to me, which makes the first phrase of your sentence seem a bit... unreliable.

Answer (score -1):

Poorly written code could make itself vulnerable to anything.  In that regard, there is nothing special about this character.

In the past, non-conforming (deliberate miscodings) UTF-8 was used by some malware to take advantage of some poorly written code.  There is still nothing special about this character.